# why is 1.2 * 30 = 35?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Why does this:

```
int main(void)
{
    short w = 30;
    return  1.2 * w;
}
```

return 35?

Comment: Broken compiler? How are you printing the resultant value?

Comment: 1.2 is not exactly representable as floating point value in general. 1.2*30 yields 35.99999 due to rounding errors, see http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: 1.2 == 1.1999999999999999555910790149937 (yes, I am slightly bored  ;p)

Comment: Floating point arithmetic strikes again!

Comment: @leppie: You seem to have omitted a few decimal places. All floating point numbers with a fractional part end in a 5 when printed in decimal.

Comment: @R..: Blame windows calculator  :)

Comment: ... and they call themselves "computer".

Comment: Why does it return 36 on some machines and 35 on others?

Comment: It should not return 36 on any machine with IEEE arithmetic.

Comment: It __will__ return 36 on AMD64. But if the code is compiled in 32-bit mode, the result will be 35.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get more suitable result, try the following:

```
return 12*w/10
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the multiplication could overflow even if the final result would fit in an `int`. Using floating point (`12.0*w/10.0`) could fix this problem.

Answer (score 12):

`1.2 * w` is `36.0`. It has the double type meaning it is not represented exactly.

Likely it turns out to be slightly less than `36`, maybe `35.99999` so when you return it the fractional part is discarded and the integer part only is returned. That's how you get `35`.

---

P.S. All operations with floating point are not precise. You should expect little discrepancies. Also when you compare a floating point value against a fixed value, you mustn't do a direct comparison but do a range comparison.

Wrong: `if (value == 36.0) { /* ... */ }`

Correct: `if (abs (value - 36.0) < 0.0001) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Spot on I reckon. If the function returned a double then we'd know for sure.

Comment: Note that `36.0` *can* be represented exactly in floating point - but `1.2` cannot.

Comment: there is no imprecision in the operation going on here. The problem is that there is no such floating point value as 1.2. It's rounded before it even gets compiled.

Comment: *"All operations with floating point are not precise"* is wrong. The modulo operation in IEEE 754-1985 is exact. Addition, subtraction, multiplication and even sometimes division are exact if you provide suitable arguments. For example `0.5 + 0.5 == 1.0` will hold true in any binary floating-point model with at least 2 bits of precision. So will `12.0 / 3.0` or `0.875 * 0.5`.

Answer (score 3):

It's an issue with binary floating point precision. `1.2` is very slightly less than 1.2, so the result of the multiplication is slightly less than 36.

Answer (score 3):

Because of representation: 1.2 is really something like 1.1999999

Answer (score 3):

Since floating point math could be inexact, use `round()` before casting to integer, to get a better result.

```
#include <math.h>
...
return (int)round(some_real_value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect absolutely exact result in floating point operations. Multiplication result may be, for example, 35.9999, which is rounded to 35.

Answer (score 0):

short w = 30;
 return  1.2 * w;

In return statement first sort value is type cast in double because 1.2 is double type
so it will multiply 1.2 * 30.000000
and result become around 35.999999 and function return type is int so decimal part is truncate and it return 35 only.