# Why is c++ giving me different answer for what looks like the same computation?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have the following source code in a simple main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double x = atof(argv[1]);
    double y = atof(argv[2]);

    double res = x + std::floor((y - x) * .5 * 100 + .5)*0.01;

    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

If I run the above with 75.21 75.22 it gives me 75.22 but if i run it with 7.21 and 7.22 it gives me 7.21. Both these number differ by 0.01 so I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: Not all numbers can be precisely defined in a floating point `double` number.

Comment: Floating-point types are not exact. Live with it.

Comment: The above code must not be your real code... for example, `main()` is declared with no parameters (`void`). Moreover, why do you use `atof()` and then assign to `int`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: He obviously doesn't know this - I'm not sure why "live with it" is a necessary response. It was an honest question, not some sort of challenge.

Comment: @slavik262: It wasn't meant as a put-down, just as honest advice: live with it and move on to something more interesting; this is not worth belabouring.

Comment: @Palace Chan Really, why don't you print your actual code?

Comment: Sorry, it was so short that I typed it out by hand and got it wrong. Apologies I edited it to be a copy paste of my main now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is 1.2 \* 30 = 35?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811355/why-is-1-2-30-35)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: floating-point values are imprecise.

The long answer: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3):

Among the many intricacies of floating-point arithmetic is the fact that floating-point numbers are not evenly distributed along the real line between their minimum and maximum values.  Close to `0` floating-point numbers, considered as points on the real number line, are denser than away from `0`, and the density decreases as the (absolute) distance from `0` increases.

For the usual IEEE standard representations there are as many numbers between, say, 1(base-10) and 2(base-10) as there are between 2(base-10) and 4(base-10).  There are the same number of floating-point numbers in the interval `[2^i,2^i+1]` for any (positive or negative) integer `i` such that both the end points of the interval are representable.

Considering this, it is not surprising that the precision of base-10 calculations decreases as the magnitude of the absolute values involved increase.

Answer (score 0):

`in x = atof ()` can not be right

```
double atof ( const char * str )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract two almost identical numbers `y` and `x`, to get a number orders of magnitude smaller than both, you *always* lose a lot of precision (except in the unlikely case that the binary expansions of both `y` and `x` terminates no later than at the 53rd bit). That's not surprising.

In this particular case, you can see the "issue" easily without tricks by just calculating

```
75.22 - 75.21
```

and

```
7.22 - 7.21
```

(the results will be `0.0100000000000051` and `0.00999999999999979`, respectively).